# A simple, repeatable hash from an UInt32 to a UInt16

Tags: c#, hash

I have a little problem where need to do a hash of a number of about 10 digits into a number of 6 digits. The hash needs to be deterministic.

It's more important that the hash is not resource intensive.

For example, say that I have some number, x, like 123456789

I want to write an hash function that gives me a number, y, back like 987654.

I'd then like to have a function that takes the x and y as parameters, re-applies the hash on x, and checks that the result is y.

It should be difficult to compute possible input values given the hash.

My first idea of multiplying pairs of digits led to a lot of duplicate hashed values.

I have the feeling that this sort of problem has some kind of elegant solution, but I just can't think of it myself.

Can anyone help me out here? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You are not entirely clear the data input and output you expect (10 _binary_ digits? _decimal_ digits? etc.). However I can say if you expect something like converting 0000000000 through 9999999999 to 000000 through 999999 then it cannot be done without some aliased (duplicate) values. 

If you actually want to convert it to a uint16 then using a simple CRC16 is about as good as any. Goodle for the code :)

Comment: Tried to clarify the question better - I'll go google CRC16 in the meantime

Comment: No matter what, you're going to get a lot of duplicates simply by casting to the smaller type - up to 2^16 worth in this case.  If you truely want to minimize duplicates, its going to be very dependant on what you're range of original values are - and based on that, you can attempt to come up with an algorithm.  Without that specific information, the best you can hope for here is a generic algorithm that may still produce lots of dups for you.

Comment: True that many duplicates are inevitable, but my first try gave about 1 in 3 which was pretty terrible! I think I've got a workable solution now, so thanks for the help. TBH I still don't quite understand why this is called hashing and not encrypting but I'll go check a dictionary!

Comment: "Encryption" implies that there is a corresponding operation called "decryption" and therefore the operation cannot be lossy. Hashing, on the other hand, is all about being lossy; it's about producing a digest that is characteristic of the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is to try to distribute the hash values as evenly as possible over the range. Some of the built in hashing methods are fairly good at this, so you could perhaps try something like getting the hash code of the string representation, and simply throw away half of the bits:

```
ushort code = (ushort)value.ToString().GetHashCode();
```

However, it also depends on what you are going to use the hash code for. The built in hash codes are not intended to be stored permanently. The algorithms for calculating the hash codes can change with any new version of the framework, so if you store the hash codes in the database they may become useless in the future. In that case you would instead have to create the hashing algorithm yourself from scratch, or use some hashing algorithm that was designed for permanent storage.

One simple algorithm that is used for hash codes for some values in the framework is to use exclusive or to make all bits in the value matter when the hash code is smaller than the data:

```
byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
ushort code = (ushort)(BitConverter.ToUInt16(b, 0) ^ BitConverter.ToUInt16(b, 2));
```

or the more efficient but less obvious way to do the same:

```
ushort code = (ushort)((value >> 16) ^ value);
```

This of course has no obfuscating properties for small values, so you might want to throw in some "random" bits to make the hash code significantly different from the value:

```
ushort code = (ushort)(0x56D4 ^ (value >> 16) ^ value);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code and the explanation! Throwing a secret number into the mix adds a simple extra element of secrecy to the method. I'm going to implement this approach.

Also, an interesting point that the built in hashing algorithms in the framework are subject to change.

Answer (score 8):

What you need is called "hashing".

Try CRC16.

Answer (score 7):

Your problem as stated is not solvable.

You say that you want the system to be "somewhat hard to break", by which I assume you mean that it is "somewhat hard" for an attacker to take a known digest and produce from it a possible input which hashes to the given digest. Since there are only 4 billion possible inputs and only 65536 possible hashes in the system you propose, it is **utterly trivial** to find a message that corresponds to a given hash, *no matter what the hash algorithm is*.  On average, the attacker will have about 65000 possible messages to choose from, and can therefore cherry-pick the message that best serves his nefarious scheme.

I would expect a "somewhat hard" problem in the hash-breaking space to require, dedicating, say, a few million dollars worth of supercomputer time to break. Your proposal can be broken by inexperienced high school students writing Javascript programs that take a couple minutes to write and maybe a minute to run, tops; this is not even vaguely close to "somewhat hard".

Why are you choosing such tiny limits on your algorithm, limits which will by their very nature make it trivial to break the hashing?  And for that matter, what's the value in hashing such a tiny amount of data as a 32 bit integer?

Answer (score 3):

(( X>>16) ^ (X)) & 0xFFFF

.......

Answer (score 0):

How about just discarding the lower 16 bits or last 4 digits?

```
1234567890 --> 123456
```

Easily done by just doing an integer division by 10000.

Comment: The point of hashing is that it would hard to construct another duplicate easily, and I think that's what the OP mean by encryption.  This method doesn't quite help.

Comment: But then he doesn't say much about what he intends to do with the value, in which case I tend to go for the simplest possible solution that would satisfy the spoken demands. Additionally, considering that for each unique 16-bit output, fully 65536 input-values will map to that output, assuming the mapping of input to output is evenly distributed. So there *will* be duplicates no matter what.

Comment: Sorry, I didnt describe my problem well. Have tried adding an example to clarify. I need an the encrypting/hashing to be harder to break than this.

Comment: How about splitting your 32-bit number in two 16-bit numbers, reversing one of them, and xor'ing the two? In any case, as others have suggested, something like CRC16 would probably work out well.